# Removing all records from a table if there is no association, in a ManytoMany relationship

Tags: postgresql

I have a M2M relations between `categories` and `items`.

```
items:

id | name  | value
1    alpha  43
2    beta   34
```

`categories` has a self referencing foreign Key.

```
id   name    parent_id
1    cat1    null
2    cat1_2  1
3    cat2    null
4    cat2_1  3
```

`categories_items` joins `items` to `categories`:

```
id   category_id item_id  
1    2           1
```

I want to delete...

1. `categories` which do not have associated `items`.
2. But keep `categories` which have a sub-category which has `items`.

In the example above `cat1` can't be deleted because its subcategory `cat1_2` is has `items`. `cat2` can be deleted, because neither itself nor its subcategory `cat2_1` have items.

I started with the following query:

```
select *
from
    categories as c
    left outer join categories_items as ci
    on ci.category_id = c.id
where
    c.id is not null
```

This doesn't work, there is no `null`, because is a M2M relations, not a FK.

Comment: "*because is a M2M relations, not a FK*" - makes no sense. many-to-many relationships also (should) have foreign key constraints

Comment: Where is the M2M switch table in your query?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete CREATE TABLE statements for `categories`, `items` and `categories_items` including all primary keys and foreign key constraints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added more info. I didn't added a full table, because is not necessary to show 20 irelevant attributes.

Comment: Is there only 1 level of subcategories?

Comment: Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=daeafff2aa7c65118083134a3d97ae61).

Comment: You had `pc.product_id = c.id` but there's no `product_id`. Presumably `product` is `item`? If so it should be referencing `category_id = c.id`, not `product_id/item_id = c.id`.